# Page number (or dot fill) in Index not placed in the right place

Tags: indexing, makeindex, dotfill

In my configuration of the Index, the `.mst` file contains the following:

```
delim_0 "\\IndexDotfill " % Filler between section heading and page number
delim_1 "\\IndexDotfill " % Filler between subsection heading and page number
```

While the command `\IndexDotfill` is defined via:

```
\newcommand*{\IndexDotfill}
  {
    \leaders \hbox to .67em {\hss \textcolor{main-text!15!paper}{.} \hss} \hfill
  }
```

This usually works quite well, but when the index text is precisely the width equaling to the space before the page number, I'm getting something weird:

[image]

As you can see from the image,

1. the first line is the expected usual behavior;
2. the second line shows the effect when there is no dot between the text and the page number, which looks not so good but is tolerable;
3. the third line is the worst case where even the page number is placed in the wrong place.

The desired behavior would be that **all page numbers are shown on the right** (even if that means to push the page number to the next line), and to always **have at least two dots before the page numbers** (by breaking the text if necessary). Currently, when the text is too long, the page number is pushed to the next line but is not on the rightmost, also there are no dots on the second line when this happens (as in the case 3 above).

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655243/194994) (kindly suggested by @campa in the comment) and its solutions seem to be quite related in achieving such a result. However, the answers there works by having a command `\itemlex` that receives two arguments. But here inside the `.ind` file, one only has the following structure:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \item ...\IndexDotfill \hyperpage{...}
```

How can one achieve the above desired behavior by improving the current definition of `\IndexDotfill`? (In particular, I've read [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592000), but the added `\hskip` doesn't seem to fit in my situation here).

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[intoc]

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.mst}
delim_0 "\\IndexDotfill " % Filler between section heading and page number
delim_1 "\\IndexDotfill " % Filler between subsection heading and page number
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand*{\IndexDotfill}
  {
    \leaders \hbox to .67em {\hss \textcolor{gray!55}{.} \hss} \hfill
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Text in case of empty.

\index{Normal}

\index{Test a text test text test text test}

\index{Test ab text test text test text test}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Difficult to test without MWE but this very recent question might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655243/82917

Comment: @campa Thank you for the suggested question! I've added a MWE to demonstrate my issues, but since the answers in your linked question are a little hard for me, it is still not clear to me how to correctly modify the dotfill macro.